# Multiple Group By LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a C#.NET application and want to do Group By on multiple conditions.
I have a list like this:

```
var testq = new List<TestQuestion>()
            {
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    QuestionId = 1,
                    SelectedAnswerId = null
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    QuestionId = 2,
                    SelectedAnswerId = 1
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id =3,
                    QuestionId = 1,
                    SelectedAnswerId = 1
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    QuestionId = 3,
                    SelectedAnswerId = 5
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    QuestionId = 1,
                    SelectedAnswerId = 2
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id = 6,
                    QuestionId = 3,
                    SelectedAnswerId = 3
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id =7,
                    QuestionId = 4,
                    SelectedAnswerId = null
                },
                new TestQuestion
                {
                    Id =8,
                    QuestionId = 5,
                    SelectedAnswerId = null
                },
            };
```

My code is :

```
  var result = testq
                .Where(p => p.SelectedAnswerId.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(p => p.QuestionId)
                .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
```

now, result ID's is  (2 ,3, 4)
but result is not true...

The result should be this :
ID's -> (2 ,3, 4, 7, 8)

I want to group by the result based on the QuestionID field and The first record that does not have a (SelectedAnswerId)field value is empty,

Also, records in which the question ID is only there once, regardless of the value of the field (SelectedAnswerId) in the output. that's mean, last two items in the list

please guide me...

Comment: The desired output is: you want a QuestionId only once regardless it has answer or not. Correct?

Comment: If it has an answer, it should give the first response that is not empty in the output, and if, after grouping, only one question that does not answer, Must be seen at the output

Comment: Please try with my answer and let me know,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = testq
            .Where(p => p.SelectedAnswerId.HasValue || testq.Count(x => x.QuestionId == p.QuestionId) == 1)
            .GroupBy(p => p.QuestionId)
            .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ogw7bn)

Comment: @MohammadGhaffariasar good news. Please mark it as answer and please do not forget to vote it up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the `SelectedAnswerId` in `Select` not in the `Where` clause. Try the below,

```
 var result = testq
             .GroupBy(p => p.QuestionId)
             .Select(p => 
              {
                 var grouped = p.ToList(); //Get the groupBy list
                 TestQuestion testQuestion = grouped.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SelectedAnswerId.HasValue); //Get anything with AnswerId
                 return testQuestion ?? grouped.FirstOrDefault(); //If not not available with Answer then get the First or Default value
              })
              .ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LEo1rp) with test data.

Comment: Your solution is true, but has more expensive than the accepted vote...

Answer (score 0):

Although after a GroupBy the order of the elements in each group is fairly defined (see [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it seems that the element that you want is not the First one in each group.

You want the First element of each group that has a non-null SelectedAnswerId, or if there is no such one, you want the First element of each group that has a null SelectedAnswerId.

How about this:

```
var result = testQ.GroupBy(question => question.QuestionId);
    // every group contains a sequence of questions with same questionId
    // select the ones with a null SelectedAnswerId and the ones with a non-null value
    .Select(group => new
    {
        NullSelectedAnswer = group
            .Where(group.SelectedAnswerId == null)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        NonNullselectedAnswer = group
            .Where(group.SelectedAnswerId != null)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    })
    // if there is any NonNullSelectedAnswer, take that one, otherwise take the null one:
    .Select(selectionResult => selectionResult.NonNullSelectedAnswer ??
                               selectionResult.NullSelectedAnswer);
```